# God's name: אֱלֹהֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל

Tags: allah, history, names, jews, bani-israel

It is common knowledge that Islam considers the Hebrew bible to be the Holy word of God. I would therefore like to know if Muslims ever refer to Allah as אֱלֹהֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל - "The God of Israel", which is how He refers to Himself over 190 times in Tanach?

If not, why not? If yes, what does it mean in Islam?

---

<sup>Note: this is an honest **religious** question aimed at deepened understanding of Islam, **not** a political one.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quran generally speaks Allah as lord of all worlds, all people etc. because it is revealed to all people irrespective of their race, region. Torah being revealed to children of Israel, that may be reason God is referred as "God of Israel" in Torah.

Israel is another name of Jacob or Yaqub (in Arabic) and in Quran you can find a verse in which Jacob is in death bed and his children referring to his God.

> Were you present when Jacob faced the hour of death and he asked his
> sons, ‘Who will you worship after me?’ They answered, ‘We will worship
> **your God** and the God of your fathers, Abraham and Ishmael and Isaac:
> the one God; we have submitted ourselves to Him.’ [Quran 2:133](https://quran.com/2/133)

so this is one reference I could find about "The God of Israel" in the Quran.

Answer (score 0):

The closest the Qur'an ever gets to mentioning God as the Lord of Israel is the verse in Chapter 7: "They complained, "“We have always been oppressed—before and after you came to us ˹with the message.” He replied, “Perhaps your Lord will destroy your enemy and make you successors in the land to see what you will do.”" (Quran 7:129). The first part of the verse is spoken by the Children of Israel to Moses. Moses replies, calling Allah "Your Lord."

And Allah knows best.